# Code coloring for SCSS in Dreamweaver

Tags: sass, dreamweaver

How to get code coloring in Dreamweaver when writing SCSS?

I got code coloring for CSS, but when I write SASS (SCSS), I get nothing but a monochromatic blueish color.

Answer (score 1):

You should open Dreamweaver then go to Edit> Preferences> File Types / Editors and in the top text box ("Open in code view:") listing various files extensions add .sass and .scss and .less

and also you must follow this [Adobe TechNote](https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/change-add-recognized-file-extensions.html)
 for applying code coloring and indentation,

when you see `winfileextension` or `macfileextension` after `css` you can add `,scss or sass , less`

that should work for you.

Comment: Sorry that does not work. I get no coloring for my code.

Comment: I have Adobe extension manager CC which does not support the type of file (.mxi) in the link you provided. It only supports (.zxp).

Comment: These links will help to resolve your problem : https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1393722 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wX8VqYMENKk